# How can I find matrices satisfying these commutation relations?

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras

Problem 1.58 in [these representation theory notes](http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf) ask us to find the dimension of the Lie algebra generated by $x$ and $y$ with defining relations $[x,[x,y]]=0$ and $[y,[y,[y,[y,x]]]]=0$.

I've managed to show that the algebra is spanned by the six elements $x$, $y$, $z$, $w$, $v$, $u$ with $[y,x]=z$, $[y,z]=w$, $[y,w]=v$, $[z,w]=[v,x]=u$, and all other brackets equal to $0$. But to show that the algebra has dimension 6, and not less than 6, I need to show that these elements are linearly independent. My strategy for that is to find six linearly independent matrices that satisfy those commutation relations, but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

Is there any good way to find matrices that satisfy those relations, or is there a better strategy to tackle this problem?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014912/show-that-the-lie-algebra-generated-by-x-y-with-relations-adx2y-ady5) addresses part (b) of the same problem, but unfortunately it doesn't help here - when we change $ad(y)^4$ to $ad(y)^5$ the structure changes significantly (in particular, it becomes infinite dimensional), and that question doesn't cover any general methods.

Comment: I would try to look for a suitable set of strictly upper triangular $7\times 7$ matrices, since that is a nilpotent Lie algebra of the right length.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that question out to me Dietrich, that one is actually part b of this same problem! I checked out the answers to that question, but I don't think they help here - when we change $ad(y)^4$ to $ad(y)^5$ the structure changes significantly (in particular, it becomes infinite dimensional), and that question doesn't cover any general methods.

Comment: @Carmeister Yes, you are right. But I did not mean that the solution is the same. Etingof's exercises have been answered several times by now, and I am pretty sure that Brian has the solution to this question (part b) as well. In this sense, it is the same exercise, and the same question as above. On the other hand, if you do not want to ask them for the solution, Tobias suggestion seems to be very reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TobiasKildetoft's suggestion in the comments, I was able to find the following two matrices:
$$x=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$y=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
A bit of calculation confirms that these satisfy the generating relations of the Lie algebra, and that the matrices $x$, $y$, $z\equiv[y,x]$, $w\equiv[y,z]$, $\equiv[y,w]$, and $u\equiv[v,x]$ are all linearly independent. So these elements must be linearly independent in the Lie algebra.

Unfortunately, I had to resort to using a computer to find these (by systematically trying a lot of matrices). I'm going to consider this problem as having been solved, but if anyone can come up with some motivation for how one might come up with these without a program, I'd still love to hear it!